# Require password even though I removed it

Tags: installation, password, authentication

Good day. One day I decided to remove the logon password from the setting. After that when I tried to change my other settings eg : install another language, Ubuntu states it required Authentication despite me removing the logon password in the setting. And when I entered the password (after removing) to authorize me, it says the password is wrong. Can anyone help? Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: This is just a guess, but try leaving the password blank and just press OK

Comment: May be this link help...

[authentication-required-to-install-plug-ins-and-application][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/280513/authentication-required-to-install-plug-ins-and-application?rq=1

Comment: Maybe [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/281074/can-i-set-my-user-account-to-have-no-password/281093#281093) can explain it a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as minerz209 says you can try leaving the password empty. However, if that doesn't solve your issue and as from your statement i believe that its the SUDO password, you're referring to .

Hence while installing new software or editing critical configuration files, it will still prompt for it. In this case If you're sure you want to remove this requirement, you can try the following command or bash

sudo visudo

Find this line:(CTRL+W)

%sudo ALL=(ALL) ALL

Edit the line:

%sudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

Thats it, in terminal you can simply become root as sudo su
and while using aptitude or others like USC, you just need to confirm you are giving the credential.

Hope this helps.